# How to run javaee7 sdk samples?

Tags: java-ee-7, glassfish-4, cargo-maven2-plugin

My teacher want me to run javaee7 sdk sample "annotation-war". Then I download the javaee7 sdk from `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html`. But, I don't know how to run it.

I have tried the following steps:

First, I import code into Intelij IDEA, and run `mvn cargo:run`, but [some error happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QjeR.png)

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\zjf\code\IDEA\javaee_samples\servlet\annotation-war -Dmaven.home=C:\zjf\soft\apache-maven-3.3.9 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\zjf\soft\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\zjf\soft\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.3 -s C:\zjf\soft\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\zjf\soft\apache-maven-3.3.9\repo org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building annotation-war 4.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run (default-cli) @ annotation-war ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.422 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-06T19:12:34+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run (default-cli) on project annotation-war: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [glassfish4x], type = [installed]], configuration type [standalone]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Then I think may be I have done the wrong thing, so I read the [docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwwZX.png) in "annotation-war". It's ok to run `mvn clean` and `mvn verify`. But when I run `mvn cargo:run -Dglassfish.home=C:\zjf\soft\glassfish`, I still encounter the same problem:

```
C:\zjf\code\IDEA\javaee_samples\servlet\annotation-war>mvn cargo:run -Dglassfish.home=C:\zjf\soft\glassfish
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building annotation-war 4.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run (default-cli) @ annotation-war ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.038 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-06T20:59:57+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run (default-cli) on project annotation-war: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [glassfish4x], type = [installed]], configuration type [standalone]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I really don't know how to run javaee SDK samples. Can anyone who know how to run it give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get it running is to first build the project with `mvn install` which will output a WAR file. The bottom of the log will tell you the full, absolute path to the WAR file. the `install` Maven goal will also put copy it to your local repository which is managed by Maven, so you will see two different paths to the same WAR file. Either of these works, e.g:

```
/path/to/my/app/target/annotation-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

You can then use the `asadmin` tool in GlassFish to deploy the WAR file, first making sure GlassFish is running:

```
C:\zjf\soft\glassfish\glassfish4\bin\asadmin start-domain
C:\zjf\soft\glassfish\glassfish4\bin\asadmin deploy /path/to/my/app/target/annotation-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

This isn't the only way to get it running (there are many) but you may find this is the easiest to undestand, with the fewest things that might go wrong, despite it being a bit long-winded.

Comment: Yes, I expect you'll get used to it eventually, then the extra instructions should get clearer and more helpful.